# Errors running e2e tests in Protractor

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I am trying to run the scenarios.js Protractor e2e test in the angularjs tutorial, here https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial. I am following the instructions on the tutorial step two in the blue box.

If I cd into the angular-phonecat directory like they say, I can run `npm install`, `npm run update-webdriver` and `npm start` without errors. I have Version 2.1.0 of protractor installed but when I try to run it I get these errors:

```
npm ERR! Darwin 14.3.0
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "protractor"
npm ERR! node v0.12.4
npm ERR! npm  v2.11.1
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! angular-phonecat@0.0.0 protractor: `protractor test/protractor-conf.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the angular-phonecat@0.0.0 protractor script 'protractor test/protractor-conf.js'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the angular-phonecat package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     protractor test/protractor-conf.js
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls angular-phonecat
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/cohenwan/Sites/angular-phonecat/npm-debug.log
```

I am not sure if the documentation for the app tutorial is faulty, but I would really like to learn how to end2end test in Protractor, but this isn't helpful. Any recommendations? Or suggestions of better ways to learn Protractor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out I needed to download chrome driver here: http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.15/. I downloaded the mac32.zip. And now it is working.